# Is there a parameter for g++ to link specified version std dynamic library?

Tags: c++

I am trying to build test.cpp with command: `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ test.cpp -o test` and I put command `readelf -d test` in terminal, the output is like this:

```
0x0000001(NEEDED)    share library:[libm.so.6]
0x0000001(NEEDED)    share library:[libstdc++.so.6]
0x0000001(NEEDED)    share library:[libgcc_s.so.1]
0x0000001(NEEDED)    share library:[libc.so.6]
```

It's not what I expect, the expected result is:

```
0x0000001(NEEDED)    share library:[libm.so]
0x0000001(NEEDED)    share library:[libstdc++.so]
0x0000001(NEEDED)    share library:[libgcc_s.so]
0x0000001(NEEDED)    share library:[libc.so]
```

I found out that there are link files(`libstdc++.so`, `libc.so`) in arm-none-gnueabi lib, so I want to know if there is a parameter for g++ to link `libstdc++.so`, `libc.so`, `libgcc_s.so`,...?

I hope someone can solving this problem. Thank you very much!

`test.cpp` code as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

gcc version is 4.8.3 20140320.

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. Why would you want this?

Comment: @user7860670 not to be dependent on library version?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès The only way to not be dependent on library version i'm aware of is not to use library at all.

Comment: To track the version is the only way to pick up the best one if there are multiple versions in parallel which can be handled by the ld.so. We all know systems which can not deal with non compatible libs(dlls) :-)

Comment: @user7860670 that is pretty rude, if not almost not practiable. If versions ensure backward compatibility, then not be dependent on version may be a goal. (Not really sure OP really want this).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Well, in this case for instance libstdc++.so.6 explicitly breaks backward compatibility when DT_SONAME differs. So one should not expect generic libstdc++.so to be compatible.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: This kind of versioning is for all practical purposes broken. "libc.so.6" is not version 6, but Glibc version 2.13-38+rpi2 or something like that.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thank you for your answar, My goal is to let "test" depend on library without version, It seems there aren't good ways to do this.